# rendering multiple elements after onClick event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I'm having problems trying to render two react elements inside a react component after a `onClick` event. Wondering if that's even possible? I'm sure I'm messing up the ternary operator, but I cannot think on another way to do what I'm trying to do ?

**TL;DR**: "When I click a button I see elementA **and** elementB"

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { showElement: true };
    this.onHandleClick = this.onHandleClick.bind(this);
  }

  onHandleClick() {
    console.log(`current state: ${this.state.showElement} and prevState: ${this.prevState}`);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ showElement: !this.state.showElement }) );
  };


  elementA() {
    <div>
      <h1>
      some data
      </h1>
    </div>
  }


  elementB() {
    <div>
      <h1>
      some data
      </h1>
    </div>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
          <button onClick={ this.onHandleClick } showElement={this.state.showElement === true}>
          </button>
          { this.state.showElement
            ?
            null
            :
            this.elementA() && this.elementB()
          }
      </section>
    )
  } 
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: It could be unrelated, but if you are using the "reducer" version of `setState` you should be doing it like this: `this.setState(prevState => ({ showElement: !prevState.showElement }) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just inattentive.

```
elementA() {
    return ( // You forget
        <div>
            <h1>
                some data
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And the same in element B.

And if You want to see both components you should change Your ternary to

```
{ this.state.showElement
            ?
            <div> {this.elementA()} {this.elementB()}</div>
            :
            null
          }
```

Another "and", for toggling `showElement` in `state` just enough
`this.setState({showElement: !this.state.showElement });`

Comment: if `state.showElement` is `true` render `null`?... A bit odd, no?

Comment: @Andrew thanks man, I've been hammering my head with this for the last couple of hours.  the `return` was a typo :)  Once again thanks man!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, (I will add comments into the code trying to explain what's going on):

```
function SomeComponentName() { // use props if you want to pass some data to this component. Meaning that if you can keep it stateless do so.
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
      some data
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { showElement: false }; // you say that initially you don't want to show it, right? So let's set it to false :)
    this.onHandleClick = this.onHandleClick.bind(this);
  }

  onHandleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ showElement: !prevState.showElement }) ); 
    // As I pointed out in the comment: when using the "reducer" version of `setState` you should use the parameter that's provided to you with the previous state, try never using the word `this` inside a "reducer" `setState` function
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
          <button onClick={ this.onHandleClick } showElement={this.state.showElement === false}>
          </button>
          { this.state.showElement
            ? [<SomeComponentName key="firstOne" />, <SomeComponentName key="secondOne" />]
            : null
          }
      </section>
    )
  } 
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Josep, just want to let you know a small thing, we can edit and undelete our answer instead of writing a new one :)

Comment: @Josep thanks for the explanation man. Although,  not understanding the part of the `keys` very well.

Comment: @intercoder have a look at this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components

Comment: @intercoder TL;DR: Whenever you are rendering an array of elements, each one of them should have a unique key... Otherwise React will yell at you a warning like "each child in an array should have a unique key prop"